# Disable Right Click in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, dom-events

How to disable right click in canvas in ReactJS. Here is what I tried which is still not working:

```
let Canvas = <canvas onContextMenu={(e)=>  {e.preventDefault(); return false;}} height={500} width={500} ref="canvas"/>;
```

A warning is also shown in browser console.

> Warning: Returning `false` from an event handler is deprecated and will be ignored in a future release. Instead, manually call e.stopPropagation() or e.preventDefault(), as appropriate.

EDIT: Yes it did stop the right click functionality on Canvas, but my problem is: I am drawing a point on left click, and **it is also being drawn on right click**, I want to disable that.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsbin.com/yecoxatile/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 12):

This JS function will prevent bubbling of the contextmenu event, thus preventing the context menu from appearing:

```
canvas.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could prevent the right-click from actually doing anything by simply ignoring it, like this:

```js
handleMouseDown = e => {
  if (e.button === 0)
  {
    // Actions to perform when left mouse button is clicked, like update state
  }
}

let Canvas = <canvas onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown} ...>;
```