# Disable right click in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following element that I would like to prevent from being downloaded by disabling the right click.

```
<iframe src={TEST + "#toolbar=0"} width="100%" height="800px" 
onMouseDown={(e)=>e.preventDefault()} onContextMenu={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}/>
```

Unfortunately, when I right-click, it still brings up the context menu. Any idea why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Right Click in React.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043748/disable-right-click-in-react-js)

Comment: No. I already saw it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: ok maybe that's because you are trying to bind events from an iframe. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30399256/2143734

Answer (score 9):

If you are using hooks then we can stop right click option in the following way

```
useEffect(() => {
        const handleContextmenu = e => {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', handleContextmenu)
        return function cleanup() {
            document.removeEventListener('contextmenu', handleContextmenu)
        }
}, [ ])
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `contextmenu` event inside `componentDidMount()` method of your component.

For example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
};
```

This will prevent the context menu to be shown.

Comment: This still didn't work. I think iframe might not be detecting any clicks because having the onClick function in iframe to a console log doesn't print anything. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Check this, you will find the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792953/onclick-function-doesnt-fire-on-iframe